# If a DLL or OCX is registered by a non-administrator user and regsvr32 says it succeeds, could it still fail to be registered properly?

Tags: dll, regsvr32

If a DLL or OCX is registered by a non-adminstrator user and regsvr32 says it succeeds, could it still fail to be registered properly?

Comment: Are there any reasons to suspect failed registration?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  For example, if `RegCreateKeyEx` is supplied `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and the user is not an administrator, it will create the key under `HKCU\Classes`. Otherwise, if the user is an admin, it will create the key under `HKLM\Classes`.

(Note the HKCU vs. HKLM distinction.  For those who aren't aware:)

```
HKCU = HKEY_CURRENT_USER
HKLM = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
```

The important thing is that some accesses to the registry, such as the example above with `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` are "demultiplexed" between the machine and user registry trees, according to the user's access.

Comment: If the entry is created under HKCU, what will happen when the DLL or OCX is accessed?

Comment: It will work just fine for the user who installed it, and not work for any other user.