# Component not registered when Run as Admin

Tags: com, vb6, ocx, regsvr32

I have an inherited app written in VB6 (yay) that runs fine locally and runs fine on the server, unless I Run As Admin at which point I get

> Error in frmTheForm (Component 'mscomctl.ocx' or one of its dependencies not correctly registered: a file is missing or invalid)

So not admin, all good, run as admin, no good.

Not a huge deal but I have several installs to do and it installs itself as a service on first run (which requires admin)

I have re-registered the OCX with no luck. The opposite situation would makes sense, any ideas what could be goint on?

Comment: Because you [installed it as a non-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2963349/11683)?

Comment: Seems pretty clear that mis-installing resulted in virtualized registration.  Perhaps the OCX itself is virtualized as well.  This might even stem from the old "just plop the OCX next to the EXE" deathtrap.  Something any programmer should know better than to do.  My guess is this is an end user and he was not given an installer at all.